# Not able to access frame's document

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I know frames has been outdated, but has i have to do my homework through frames only.
Can anyone please check what's wrong in this code?

Main Web page :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FFCS- Student Login</title>




<frameset rows="25%,70%,5%">
 <frame name="banner" src="sh.html"/>
<frameset cols="21%,79%">
 <frame src="f1.html"/>
 <frame src="f2.html"/>
</frameset>
<frame src="pr.html"/>
</frameset>

<script>
var nAme=prompt("Enter your name: ");
var regno=prompt("Enter your Register No: ");
window.frames["frame_name"].document.getElementById("naa").innerHTML = nAme;
window.frames["frame_name"].document.getElementById("regno").innerHTML = regno;
</script>
</head>
<html>
```

sh.html [frame name=banner] :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body{margin: 0}
</style>
<head>
<body>

<table id="id1" background="banner_bg3.jpg" width="100%" height="15%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="25%"><img src="vit_logo6.jpg" alt="logo"></td>
<td align=center>
 <font size=5 color=#FFFFFF face="Comic Sans MS">
<b>V-TOP</b><br>Student Login</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width="100%" height="2%" bgcolor=#000000 align="center">
   <td align=left width="41%">
    <font face=verdana color=#FFFFFF size=2>
    
     Welcome <b id="naa" style="color:white;">Adhik N A</b> - <b id="regno" style="color:white;">15BIT0169</b> - SITE

    </font>
   </td>
   <td align=center width="23%">
    <font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Logout</b></font></a>
   </td>
   <td align=right width="36%">
    <font face=verdana color=#FFFFFF size=2><p id="demo"></p>
<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();</script></font>&nbsp;
   </td>
</table>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td rowspan="

<iframe src="f2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i accessing the frame's documents in the right way ?

Comment: because the frame is not fully loaded? What is the error you get in the browser's console? And in this modern age, why are you using font tags? It is not the 90s

Comment: One thing wrong with this is that you are trying to put the frameset in the head, rather than after it. And like @epascarello says, it's not recommended to use elements that were deprecated in 1999, but if you really want to, you should consider using a HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype, so that you can validate your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly (you don't say what goes wrong exactly)

You can't access an element in a frame from the parent document.
Solution: move the JavaScript routine into the frame.